# Syncing profile pictures from Azure Active Directory to Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, office365

I have created an Azure DevOps organization and it has been successfully linked with my Azure AD tenant, group search in the organization correctly shows Azure Active Directory (security) groups.

My user however does not have the correct profile picture in Azure DevOps. In Office 365 and in Azure AD my profile picture shows up correctly, but in Azure DevOps only my initials show up in a colored circle.

Is there a missing setting to make user profile pictures show up in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click the circular image showing the user's initials in the upper right corner of the organization page, and then you will see my profile options and click it. Then you can set up your own profile picture by clicking Edit Profile.

After completing all the above steps, please wait a moment, because the server may need some time to synchronize settings and display user profile images in the organization.

Please note that in some pages, users will still display their initials, such as commit history, build author, etc. But in Azure Boards, user's profile pictures can display normally.

Comment: I have already added a picture in Azure Active Directory, I want to avoid that everybody needs to upload a profile picture in Azure Active Directory AND Azure Devops

Comment: I'm sorry to say that at present, your team can only upload its own user profile pictures one by one. Although many users have responded to this kind of problem to us, this feature has not been released on Azure DevOps yet. If it has the latest changes, please pay attention to  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @BobBen is there a user voice or similar proposal I can vote for?

Comment: I think this is what you want [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365621/make-user-vsts-user-profile-sync-from-corporate-az.html)

Answer (score 1):

In my organization, our Azure DevOps account is linked to our Microsoft account which is tied to Active Directory (I'm not even sure I have that correct, I can't keep track of where my Microsoft info is stored).

I changed my picture a while back but the new one didn't show up in DevOps. I would click my profile picture in the top-right, click "View Account", and it took my to a central account page where my profile picture was correct.

This made me believe it was a server-side sync/cache issue. I waited over a week and it didn't update.

Finally I realized I needed to click the profile icon *next to* my picture, then click Profile from there. That leads to a separate page where I can change my picture & other info which is effective only in DevOps.

[image: screenshot of DevOps Profile link]