# Azure AD profile photo not showing in right corner

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am a member of this Azure Subscription: `Visual Studio Enterprise - MPN`. In the Azure Portal, I created a new tenant and added my custom domain to it that I bought from a Domain Registrar. The new domains works fine. I have also successfully added profile picture to the domain using this [Official Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-profile-azure-portal). But even after about six hours, the picture does not show up on the upper right corner when I login to the Azure Portal `with the new domain login`.

**Question**: What I may be missing, and how can we have the picture show up?

**Remarks**: My online search shows some relevant links such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56277474/1232087) and [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-365-profile-photo-not-showing-in-right/f1aac7c5-257e-41c6-9dbf-1c2d1462cc31) but these links seem to have different contexts.

**My Custom Domain Login at the top right corner**:

[image]

**When click on the `View account link` (shown above), profile picture shows displays as expected**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would give it 24 hours. microsoft does not work in realtime. There are various systems that need to sync when you make changes. for example, if you change an office 365 group, it could take up to 24 hours for the changes to get to microsoft teams, exchange, sharepoint. etc. some of those systems have their own backend data storage and take time to sync.